# How can I push a URL to several phones and tablets when doing development?

Tags: android, ios, windows-mobile

Smartphone and tablet use is so diverse now that the only way to see if a website is actually rendering properly is to directly view it on the device itself (especially if it is an interactive bug).

Is there a way I can push a url to several devices in front of me?

I'd really want to do this in-house and not use an outside service if possible since this is for development.

If I have to do a one-time configuration on each device that is fine of course but the idea is that it would go to the url by itself as if it was entered directly.

I've seen "pushbullet" and apparently there used to be service called [Site-To-Phone](http://www.guidingtech.com/17897/instantly-push-links-any-browser-smartphone/) that no longer exists, but again, in-house would be best.

Comment: if you want in house, you can always make something on your own. Actually its a great idea and you should go ahead and make something similar and release it under Apache :)

Comment: @Kay so far the easiest idea I've come up with is to make the home page on each browser on each device set to a webpage that polls via JS to a webpage which then broadcasts whatever url I push to it. Of course once off that homepage it no-longer works. Unless maybe I can make that homepage open tabs/windows so it stays active but few mobile browser support that.

Comment: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/tooling/synchronized-cross-device-testing/

Comment: @Kay oh that is a great article, many thanks, you should post it as a answer for credit